# Any way to cancel signal propagation in boost signals2 without exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, boost, signals, boost-signals2

I'd like to use `boost::signals2` to handle event notification in my C++ app. I'm hoping to implement  something with similar functionality to browser DOM events, specifically the ability to stop the propagation of an event so that the current receiver is the last one to know about a signal and subsequent receivers are not called. (see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-stopImmediatePropagation for more on how this works in browsers)

I have a hypothetical `App` class with a signal called `thingHappened`. It's likely there'll only be one `App` instance, with several other `Widget` classes of varying types that will `connect` to `thingHappened` to receive `ThingEvent` notifications. Sometimes the widget would like to consume (stop) the `ThingEvent` so that no other `Widget`s are notified.

At first I wondered if I could achieve this with a `shared_connection_block` but now I understand that this only suppresses one connection at a time. Initially I passed a `shared_ptr<ThingEvent>` to my signal but once the signal was called there was no way to intervene with its propagation. If I pass a shared_ptr I could have signal receivers check a value on the event and return if it's set, but I don't want to push that detail off to users of my library.

The solution I've found is to pass a `ThingEvent` on the stack so that it is copied for each receiver. If I set `mStopPropagation` on the event then when it is destroyed I can throw an exception and the signal calls terminate. The downside to this is that I need my own try/catch at the point where the signal is called, and stylistically it means I'm using an `exception` for an unexceptional purpose. Is there a better way?

Here's my hypothetical `App` class, with a signal `thingHappened`:

```
class App
{
public:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (class ThingEvent)> thingHappened;
};
```

My `ThingEvent` class, with some data about the event (e.g. type) and an `mStopPropagation` property that will cause an exception to be thrown if it is set in the destructor:

```
class ThingEvent
{
public:
    ThingEvent(string type): mType(type), mStopPropagation(false) { }

    ~ThingEvent() 
    {
        if (mStopPropagation) {
            throw exception();
        }
    }

    void stopPropagation() { mStopPropagation = true; }

    string getType() { return mType; }

private:
    string mType;
    bool mStopPropagation;

};
```

Here's a sample signal consumer, a `Widget`, that will call `stopPropagation()` on an `event` if the type is `"goat"`:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(string name): mName(name) {}

    ~Widget() {}

    void thingHappened(ThingEvent thing)
    { 
        cout << thing.getType() << " thingHappened in widget " << mName << endl; 

        if (thing.getType() == "goat") {
            thing.stopPropagation();
        }
    }

    string getName() 
    {
        return mName;
    }

private:
    string mName;
};
```

Finally, here's a quick `main()` function that uses these classes:

```
int main()
{
    App app;

    Widget w1("1");
    Widget w2("2");
    Widget w3("3");

    boost::signals2::connection c1 = app.thingHappened.connect(boost::bind(&Widget::thingHappened, &w1, _1));
    boost::signals2::connection c2 = app.thingHappened.connect(boost::bind(&Widget::thingHappened, &w2, _1));
    boost::signals2::connection c3 = app.thingHappened.connect(boost::bind(&Widget::thingHappened, &w3, _1));

    // all three widgets will receive this
    app.thingHappened(ThingEvent("otter"));

    {
        // suppress calls to c2
        boost::signals2::shared_connection_block block(c2,true);
        // only w1 and w3 will receive this
        app.thingHappened(ThingEvent("badger"));
    }

    // Widgets call ThingEvent::stopPropagation() if the type is "goat"
    try {
        // only w1 will receive this
        app.thingHappened(ThingEvent("goat"));
    } catch (exception &e) {
        // ThingEvent's destructor throws if mStopPropagation is true
        std::cout << "exception thrown by thingHappened(goat)" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you have boost to hand (I'm using 1.44) and you want to compile it, the full code and Makefile are at https://gist.github.com/1445230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a custom signal combiner.  These are explained in the "Signal Return Values (Advanced)" section of the boost.signals tutorial: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id3070223

Here's the gist of it:

```
struct MyCombiner {
    typedef bool result_type;
    template <typename InputIterator> result_type operator()(InputIterator aFirstObserver, InputIterator aLastObserver) const {
        result_type val = false;
        for (; aFirstObserver != aLastObserver && !val; ++aFirstObserver)  {
            val = *aFirstObserver;            
        }
        return val;
    }
};
```

The input iterators to operator() refer to the collection of slots for the signal.  Each time you dereference one of the iterators, it calls the slot.  So you can let one of the slots return a value to indicate that it doesn't want any further slots to be called.

Then you just pass it in to the second template arg of your signal:

```
boost::signals2::signal<bool(ThingEvent), MyCombiner> sig;
```

Now you can implement thingHappened to return a bool value indicating whether or not you want the signal to be stopped.

Comment: I see now how the combiner works, thank you! I think I can use a stopPropagation method on my ThingEvent if I move back to a shared_ptr<ThingEvent> and use app.thingHappened.set_combiner(MyCombiner(event)) before calling the signal with the same event. I don't need to call thingHappened from different threads so I think this is fine. I updated my github link to reflect this implementation.